# Laravel Error Message if no checkbox is checked

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, flash-message

I'm trying to build up a shop and I've tried multiple things to create an error message to display an alert. If the user haven't checked any checkbox, but tried to submit the form, then the error message should appear. I was able to display the error message on the right page, but this causes more trouble. If the user did everything correct, he will get directed to the next page where he can add some tags to his products. The request for adding text, was displaying some error messages if there are any errors but this doesn't work anymore, after I've coded the alert message on the page before. Now if the user will do something wrong, with putting some new tags to his product and tries to submit the form, then my code just loops until my browser crashes.

Controller:

```
 public function edit()
    {

    // some non important controller code 
    if(count(Input::get('id')) == 0)
    {
        Session::flash('danger', 'Sie haben kein Produkt gewählt!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    else
    {
        return view('layout.edit.productedit', [
            'ids' => $data,                  // non important variables
            'products' => $product_name        
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in my view:

```
@if (Session::has('danger'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('danger') }}</div>
@endif
```

This works Like I want it, If the user haven't checked any checkboxes, he gets redirected with the error message. If he did checked any checkbox, he will get to the next page where he can add some tags.

On the next page is just a simple textbox where he can create some tags. Before I did this error message, the user got some error message from my tagsrequest ( if there were some problems att all ). Now, he doesn't get anything from my tagsrequest after submitting the form and my browser crashes because my code is just looping again and again

does anyone see why? I don't understand how this error message affects my other page and his request.

Comment: maybe someone can show me another way for adding a textmessage? thats the only way I know :)

Comment: Have you included this file into your other file?if so that may be the reason

Comment: No I didn't. I still don't have any idea how I can make this. Maybe with a javascript solution

Comment: find edit() in your other file

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-i-validate-checkboxs-in-a-form?page=1

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-validation-input-format

try this solutions

Comment: $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required'
        ]);